# Racket [v8.6 Beginning Student] Simplify the function

Tags: scheme, racket

The function is:

```
(define (q3a p1? p2?)
  (cond
    [p2? (cond [p1? 'left]
                [else 'down])]
    [else (cond [p1? 'up]
                [else 'right])]))

(define (q3b p1? p2?)
  (cond [p1? (cond
              [p2? (cond
                     [p1? 'up]
                     [p2? 'down]
                     [else 'right])]
              [else (cond
                      [p2? 'down]
                      [else 'up])])]
       [(and p1? false) (cond
                          [p2? 'left]
                          [else 'right])]
       [else 'down]))

(define (q3c p1? p2?)
  (cond [(cond [p1? p2?]
               [else true])
         'up]
    [else 'down]))
```

I am tasked with simplifying this function. Note that there are some identical outputs, namely: `(q3a true false)=(q3b true false)`, `(q3b true true)=(q3c true true)`, and `(q3a false true)=(q3b false true)`. It is also worth mentioning that only `up` and `down` are valid outputs for `q3b` and `q3c`. I have tried eliminating `left` and `right` from these functions with little success. Any hints or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs135/assign/a02/a02.pdf

Comment: (and expr false) is the same as ... false, surely? You've mistyped. @molbdnilo

Comment: @WillNess You seem to make a habit of correcting me ;-) I appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Never for the sake of correcting, only for the sake of correctness (for the benefit of the new learners). :) @molbdnilo

Answer (score 2):

1. is simple:

```
(define (q3a p1? p2?)
  (cond
    [p2? (cond [p1? 'left]
                [else 'down])]
    [else (cond [p1? 'up]
                [else 'right])]))
= ; two-clause cond is an if:
(define (q3a p1? p2?)
  (if p2?
    (if p1? 'left 'down)
    (if p1? 'up 'right)))
```

2. is much longer. I'll give you its hints, see if you can follow it through:

```
(define (q3b p1? p2?)
  (cond [p1? (cond
              [p2? (cond
                     [p1? 'up]
                     [p2? 'down]
                     [else 'right])]
              [else (cond
                      [p2? 'down]
                      [else 'up])])]
       [(and p1? false) (cond
                          [p2? 'left]
                          [else 'right])]
       [else 'down]))
= ; (and x false) is always false:
= ; two-clause cond is an if:
= ; the else of x is (not x):
= ; x and (not x) can never hold at the same time:
= ; lone else in cond is redundant:
= ; two-clause cond is an if:
= ; if's test inside first clause is always true:
= ; the first true clause of cond is its value:
= ; if with same value in both clauses is no if at all:
(define (q3b p1? p2?)
  (..........))  ; one short expression
```

3. is the most interesting one:

```
(define (q3c p1? p2?)
  (cond [(cond [p1? p2?]
               [else true])
         'up]
    [else 'down]))
= ; you know this one by now:
= ; and again:
= ; if with negated test has clauses flipped:
= ; (if x true y) means (or x y)
(define (q3c p1? p2?)
  (if (........)
    'up
    'down))
```

Try finishing it up, it should be fun.